# How are sessions handled in flutter?

Tags: flutter, authentication, cookies

Does flutter support cookies on android and ios? How do we handle the client side of session based authentication in flutter?

Comment: I don't know if it is a suitable solution but for me i would implement a session management in backend (ex: flask with sessions) and send a sessionID to the flutter client. The client then save it in preferences with shared_preferences package.